# Click on something behind a transparent image?

Tags: jquery, html

Couldn't find exactly what I was looking for so if this his been answered already please excuse me. I have a simple setup which is a PNG image with a few transparent spots in which I have videos and other things going on. These are of course behind the image in terms of z-index so that they are masked out by the PNG. However, I want the user to be able to interact with these things, and they cannot, since the image having a higher z-index only allows focus to that element.
Any ideas?

Comment: What is the deal to add a transparent layer in front of clickable element?

Comment: [**Pointer events**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/pointer-events) should probably work in modern browsers, if crappy browsers needs to be supported, you'll need to figure out the position of the elements relative to the mouse pointer and capture / trigger events, which is a helluva lot of trouble if you ask me, and I would redesign everything before I did that.

Comment: pointer-events:none; on the image css worked, good on FF and Safari at least

Comment: Why PNG image overlay in front? Why not in back? Sorry, IMO it just makes no sense to mask clickable/hoverable items behind overlay, then delegate events to them. If it's interactive then it should be interactive.

Comment: How could I mask the items with a PNG in back of them?

Comment: That depends on what you are masking and the layout of the page. For example, if you're masked area edges aren't covering any controls, you can have side and top graphics to cover just the side and top around the thing you are masking rather than having one huge png covering the entire thing.

Comment: I see, true that. This is easier though